# DFP returning empty vast files (ads)

Tags: fiddler, ads, double-click

I am using DFP to serve ads, and fiddler to monitor the requests.

After 3 GET requests to the dfp server, in a short period of time (say 30 seconds), every subsequent request will a list of empty ads.

Does DFP have some sort of spam protection? if so, is there a way around it? debugging an ad implementation is quite slow when you're ad payloads are empty!

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some rate limiting going on within DFP... I have run into this many times! I think it may be per ad unit from what I can tell... and it doesn't last very long....

As for debugging have your tried the DFP google console? That makes debugging a lot easier... and I am pretty sure it will give you the diagnostics you need to debug without the rate limit being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into adding a "corrolator" value in the parameters?
Just &c=rand(10000,99999).